# Mac photo booth on cv2 python, why does my code result in an error?

Tags: python, opencv

I want the code to take 4 pics with a 1 second interval using cv2, then add the together using hconcat function. When I try to run this code I get ('numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'release'), can someone help

```
import cv2,random
num = random.randint(0,2000)
cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cv2.namedWindow("Mac")

def concat_tile(im_list_2d):
    return cv2.vconcat([cv2.hconcat(im_list_h) for im_list_h in im_list_2d])

x = []
for i in range(4):
    ret,frame = cam.read()
    x.append(frame)
    frame.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

im_v = concat_tile([[x[0],x[1]],
                    [x[2],x[3]]])
img_name = "opencv_frame_{}.png".format(num)
cv2.imwrite(img_name,im_v)
```

Answer (score 0):

It should not be `frame.release()`, rather try `cam.release()`

Also, `release()` and `cv2.destroyAllWindows()`, should be written at the end of your code, not within the for loop

```
for i in range(4):
    ret,frame = cam.read()
    x.append(frame)

cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```